# Logarithm inequality $\log (25 + 5^{2x}) > x(1-\log 2) + \log 2 + \log13$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> known 
>   $\log (25 + 5^{2x}) > x(1-\log 2) + \log 2 + \log13$

Find range of $x$
Options : $x<0 \cup x>2$

$0<x<2$

$x>2$

$x\leq 0 \cup x>2$
By substituting i find $x=0,x=1$ not sufficient.
So the answer is$x<0 \cup x>2$
But how to solve it manually since i tried but not find it

Some hints anyone?

Comment: The log base matters here (e.g. in base 2, the x term vanishes), so you might want to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the base $=10$

and using $\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$ and $\log(a/b)=\log a-\log b$

$$(25+25^x)/26>5^x$$

Set $5^x=y$ to find $$0<y^2-26y+25=(y-1)(y-25)$$

So either $y<1$ or $y >25$

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

1. Differentiate the function $f(x)=\log (25 + 5^{2x}) - x(1-\log 2) - \log 2 - \log13$. $$f'(x)\begin{cases}\leq0 &\text{ for } x\leq1\\
   >0&\text{ for } x>1.\end{cases}$$
2. $f(0)=f(2)=0$

Comment: Thanks. The first time i knew that log can be solved with differentiation.. but i just cant work it out yet

Comment: what is your difficulty? $f'(x)=\frac{2\times5^{2x}\log 5}{25+5^{2x}}-(1-\log 2)=\log 5\left[2-\frac{50}{25+5^{2x}}\right]-\log5=\log 5\left[1-\frac{50}{25+5^{2x}}\right]$. So $f'(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$ and $f(1)=0$.